# Gnome 2 desktop shortcut: Run a script having commands changing the environment

Tags: gnome

I want to launch a script (that ultimately launches an editor) with a single click in GNOME 2. To this end I have a script which sources the environment variables first and then ultimately launches the editor. The script looks something like:

```
#!/bin/sh
source variablesFile
editor $1
```

From the terminal I can easily launch the editor with:

```
$ ~/script myFile.txt
```

Now, what I want to achieve is have an icon in the taskbar/Desktop, from which I can double click and start typing, just like gedit.

I tried the following way:

[image]

but it did not work (mostly because the environment variables could not be changed).

I also tried:

[image]

but a terminal window flashed and went away. No idea what happened. Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to launch a terminal (here `xterm`), and run the script (which launches the editor) as an argument to it. Later we can shortcut the `launchScript` into the Gnome shortcut.

The launch script looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
xterm -e /path/to/editor/launch/script.sh
```

Now we point the shortcut to this file:
[image]

This retains the values of environment variables, as we are running a script from a terminal.

Note: In this approach the `xterm` window vanishes, as soon as the editor is launched. To hold this window, use the following command:
`xterm -hold -e /path/to/editor/launch/script.sh` .